# Read-only access to MMC functionality

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, mmc

Does anyone know of a Windows Server 2008 role(s) to allow readonly access to MMC (MS Management Console) facilities - i.e. we would like to be able to remotely view (*not* add/update/delete) "Administrative Tools" functionality such as IIS websites, Event log, Users and groups, status of services, etc.  This is so we can connect to a say a Development server (administered by another team) to check configuration before/during deployment via say Administive Tools | Computer Management | Connect to another computer
Many thanks
Travis